# Page view displays not properly after update wordpress

Tags: pages, users, updates

I have a problem at WP backend: the page view not shows any pages but just for a few users. For admin and for other users the backend is still working. (The site uses the version 4.5.2 now.)
Any suggestions?

Comment: plz explain your question more or need to see the snapshot,

Comment: Ok, more detailed: when I click at the Pages from the side menu in backend, it displays "pages not found". (it's actually not true, I have more than 400 pages). Up in the submenu it shows the correct numbers, so it counts but displays nothing. The site has more than 20 users and this problem is not in every users backend. Admin backend is also fine.

Comment: try deactivating all active plugins, then check if pages are displaying then activate plugin one by one to check which one is culprit

Comment: when all the plugins are deactivated, it also doesn't work. "No pages found" still...